# Refreshing standard lightning components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-events

I have overridden the detail page of case layout and added standard activity component. I have another custom component which is creating tasks.

Problem I am facing is that whenever custom component is creates activity, I want that to be reflected on the standard activity component.

I am firing e.force:refreshView event but it only refreshes the detail page and not any other standard component on the page.

Is there any solution to refresh the standard component without reloading the entire page?